# Implementing Twitter Bootstrap Modal

Tags: twitter, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty new to coding, so please pardon my inexperience.

I'm currently working on making a website, and want to have button modals. I can't seem to get it working, and have experimented with it for at least a few hours. This is what I have written in my html file, which was taken from the Twitter Bootstrap site:

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" >Launch Modal</a>

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Am I missing something here? Do I need add something else? The bootstrap site said to "call the modal via javascript", but I didn't know where to put the $('#myModal').modal(options). I placed it in the .html AND the .js file, but neither attempt worked.

The .html file already has

```
<script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
```

along with all the other plugins, but this doesn't seem to be doing anything. It's also worth noting that I am working locally on my computer.

I'm sure this is a very easy question, but ANY help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**:I managed to get it working. Looked like my problem was that I was sourcing bootstrap-modal.js, when really I only had bootstrap.js. I made a new file called boostrap-modal.js with the code, and it worked fine.

However, I'm still unable to get the fade in transition. I've used the bootstrap-transition.js files but still can't seem to get it down. Additional help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not get a simple bootstrap modal to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560630/can-not-get-a-simple-bootstrap-modal-to-work)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<sub>* Updated the bootstrap stylesheet path on the fiddle, it changed since I wrote this answer.</sub>

You need to include the jQuery script before the bootstrap-modal.js script file for the plugin to work, here is the script straight from googles CDN that you can include freely in your page, just make sure to include it **before** any js that you might have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You only need to call the script if you want it to display when your page loads, otherwise you just need to have the proper `data-*` attribute and `href` reference in your modal button which you already have:

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" >Launch Modal</a>
```

You can include all scripts at the end of your `<body>` tag for faster content loading, the same way the twitters bootstrap demo page has it.

Here is a demo of a modal page:

http://jsfiddle.net/3v2zg/626/

Comment: Thank you for taking the time in answering my question, I really appreciate it.

I took the script that you provided and placed it before all the others at the end of the body like you said, but it still didn't work.

What's happening when I use the code I provided up above, is that upon load of the page, the modal is already opened (without clicking the button) and  is unresponsive to clicking the "Close" "Save changes" or "x" buttons. 

When I use the code you provided, the modal just doesn't open.
Maybe I'm missing something else?

Comment: @PatrickE. The code you provided above should work just fine, granted that you have all script files properly loaded in your document. Since the modal is being called by an data attribute in your "lauch" link, you don't really need to provide the js call for the modal, that is only supplied if you want to load up the modal when your content loads (as in, automatically). You're also missing the `.hide` class inside of your modal container, that is what "hides" the modal until called, so add that as well, e.g. `<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is working, and I'm really happy because my site features modals a lot. I'm a newb at coding, but I figured I'll just START coding a website, even if it's bad, and that I'll learn along the way. I find this to be better because learning how to code BEFORE making a site can seem like a pretty big task.

Anyway, it looked like the problem was the script files. I'm currently having trouble with the transition (using the file bootstrap-transition.js). Transition fades would be a really nice plus. Any thoughts? Do I need to add the ajax jquery script you provided earlier again?

Comment: Without the jQuery script loaded, the modal script will not function so make sure to have one instance of the script included. The transition.js file is used to add effects to the bootstrap scripts, without it you won't have any effects on your page, it basically uses CSS3 to pull off most effects so make sure you're testing on a updated browser. To include the effect on your modal window make sure to include the `.fade` class on its container, like so: `<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">` notice the fade class, that is there for that same reason, for the fade effect.

Comment: Finally got it working! Thanks a ton! You've been so helpful, and I was worried no one would answer my question, considering this website was my last resort!



Thanks,